# Why an exception thrown from finally block ignores an exception thrown from catch block?

Tags: java, exception

Can anyone give me a reason why `new Exception()` is ignored here?

```
void bar() throws IOException { //no Exception declared, compilator is ok about that. Why?
 try{
   throw new EOFException();
 }
 catch(EOFException eofe){
   throw new Exception();
 }
 finally{
    throw new IOException();
 }
}
```

Comment: Because there is no way for the function to throw `EOFException` or `Exception`, as `IOException` will always preempt them.

Comment: Yes but why compilator doesn't complain about we haven't added `throws Exception` in method declaration?

Comment: @Oleksandr If the finally block completes abruptly for reason S, then the try statement completes abruptly for reason S (and the throw of value V is discarded and forgotten). ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The finally block is always executed, regardless of whether the try block throws an exception or not (and regardless of whether it has a return statement or not).

Therefore, the exception thrown by the finally block - `IOException` - is the only exception thrown by your method, and it's always thrown, regardless of the content of the try block. Therefore your method only has to declare that it `throws IOException`.